# How to solve Google Alternate page with proper canonical tag issue

Tags: indexing, canonical-link

Google repeatly reports "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" errors despite having fixed the issue at least six times. The issue appears not to have a solution. I have the following tag in each of my pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page.html"/>
```

If I comment this out for all pages except the index.html page and then add the following meta tag to the other pages, would this be a solution?

```
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex">
```

Comment: Google appears to indicate this may be due to similar URLs being appropriate for specific devices. Canonical links should allow for similar pages to be identified as being one page so 'page.html?page=2' is referring to 'page.html' but this error is displayed. We need the pages to be indexed to allow them to appear on Google.